# How to join all columns from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried doing this but it failed.

```
SELECT table2.ID, table1.* FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.ID = table2.table1ID
```

How do you select all columns from a table?

EDIT: There is no error in the above query. I don't know what caused the error but the code is now working.

Comment: Change the question to "How to join all columns from one table" it is a better topic. SELECT tablename.* could easily be misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is syntactically correct, exactly what did you mean by it failed? Did you get an error message or just not the results you wanted? (BTW it is a bad practice to select *, only return the columns you need. In this case you do not need all the columns as the id field in table1 will have the exact same data as the file din table 2 it is joined to)

Comment: Thanks HLGEM! Why is it bad to select *? What if I have 20 columns and I need 18 of them? Thanks.

Comment: Select * should not ever be used in production servers as it sends more infomation than you need across the network which creates performance problems over time. Further, if you change the structure of the table, select * gives the wrong results, so suddenly your report that is supposed to have ten columns has eleven. And if someone foolishly changed the order of the columns in the table, you may have the wrong data in the wrong column.

Answer (score 3):

You had field names conflict as both tables have ID field. You must to

```
 SELECT table2.ID as t2_id, table1.* FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.ID = table2.table1ID
```

Comment: A field name conflict won't prevent the query from running.

Comment: It was not said how it failed

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT t2.ID, t1.* FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.ID = t2.table1ID
```

this works on sql 2000+

Answer (score 0):

If I am working inside a stored procedure where I have a defined @Table data type, there is no issue with using select table.* especially if I am using it for an output SELECT at the end. So the comment about production servers and network traffic in this case is meaningless as the entire stored procedure executes in memory. A select.* in this case is merely returning all the columns which have been defined ahead of time.